# How to call a function on particular page like 'contact-us' from function.php of child theme

Tags: functions

I want to call  a function on particular page like 'contact-us' from function.php of child theme.

i tried this function

```
 if( is_page('contact-us')) {

    echo "hello check"; 
     //either in about us, or contact, or management page is in view
 } else {
     echo "Not working";
 }
```

But getting else part on every page.

```
 if(is_page(37)){
     echo "page 37";
 } else {  echo "Not working" }
```

Getting else part

```
$current_url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  $contactUsId = url_to_postid( $current_url ); 

  if($contactUsId == '37'){

echo "hello";
}
```

But this works , can any one one help me to know why first two function print else part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use `is_page()`, a conditional function intended only to run adjacent to the query, too early. Try running your code inside a callback that 1) only fires on the front-end, 2) fires after the page has partially loaded. For instance, `wp_head`.

```
function prefix_run_on_contact_us() {
    if( is_page('contact-us')) {
        echo "hello check"; 
        //either in about us, or contact, or management page is in view
    } else {
        echo "Not working";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'prefix_run_on_contact_us' );
```

Comment: I also suggest making sure you've enabled `WP_DEBUG` while testing things like this. If you try to use `is_page()` before `$wp_query` is set, a `_doing_it_wrong()` notice describing this exact problem will get printed. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What hook do You use when You try use this functions? Did You think about it? It happen me all the time :) Here You have earliest possible hook in my opinion i tested few and they were too soon.

Solution 1:

```
add_action('parse_query', function () {

if( is_page('contact-us')) {

    echo "hello check";
    //either in about us, or contact, or management page is in view
} else {
    echo "Not working";
}});
```

Solution 2:

```
add_action('parse_query', function () {

    if( 'contact-us' == get_query_var('pagename') ) {
        echo "hello check";
        //either in about us, or contact, or management page is in view
    } else {
        echo "Not working";
    }
});
```